# I cant grab columns from a table in a database in python

Tags: python, database, ms-access, multiple-columns, command-prompt

I am trying to grab information from columns in a database using python.

code:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=MACCD')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT first,second,third,fourth,fifth * FROM Test')


for column in cursor.fetchall():
    print(column)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jgp22\Desktop\Python\GrabDatas.py", line 5, in <module>
cursor.execute('SELECT first,second,third,fourth,fifth * FROM Test')
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft 
Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'fifth 
*'. (-3100) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bad SQL query. Cannot put * like that in select queries

Either put a comma before asterisk

```
SELECT first,second,third,fourth,fifth,* FROM Test;
```

Or remove asterisk

asterisk is used to represent all columns in sql so using it in your query means you are fetching all columns, therefore it is useless in this scenario to use asterisk is u want only few columns

Comment: @jonathania u shouldnt use ,* though if u donot want all columns cause it will fetch all columns accept answer if it helped

Comment: thank you I didn't notice because the id was added to the end.  Thank You